# Haskell fast text processing

Tags: performance, haskell

I am working on function to convert javascript encoded unicode string from server api to utf8.

I have 2 approaches. The first is not general enough, and second is too slow.
How can I do it both fast and for all unicode symbols?

First is just replacing some substring using Map

```
ununicode :: BL.ByteString -> BL.ByteString               
ununicode s = LE.encodeUtf8 $ replace $ LE.decodeUtf8 s where 
  replace :: L.Text -> L.Text
  replace "" = ""
  replace string = case Map.lookup (L.take 6 string) table of
          (Just x)  -> L.append x (replace $ L.drop 6 string)
          Nothing   -> L.cons (L.head string) (replace $ L.tail string)

  table = Map.fromList $ zip letters rus

  rus =  ["Ё", "ё", "А", "Б", "В", "Г", "Д", "Е", "Ж", "З", "И", "Й", "К", "Л", "М",
         "Н", "О", "П", "Р", "С", "Т", "У", "Ф", "Х", "Ц", "Ч", "Ш", "Щ", "Ъ", "Ы",
         "Ь", "Э", "Ю", "Я", "а", "б", "в", "г", "д", "е", "ж", "з", "и", "й", "к",
         "л", "м", "н", "о", "п", "р", "с", "т", "у", "ф", "х", "ц", "ч", "ш", "щ",
         "ъ", "ы", "ь", "э", "ю", "я", "—"]  :: [L.Text]

  letters = ["\\u0401", "\\u0451", "\\u0410", "\\u0411", "\\u0412", "\\u0413", 
             "\\u0414", "\\u0415", "\\u0416", "\\u0417", "\\u0418", "\\u0419",
             "\\u041a", "\\u041b", "\\u041c", "\\u041d", "\\u041e", "\\u041f",
             "\\u0420", "\\u0421", "\\u0422", "\\u0423", "\\u0424", "\\u0425",
             "\\u0426", "\\u0427", "\\u0428", "\\u0429", "\\u042a", "\\u042b",
             "\\u042c", "\\u042d", "\\u042e", "\\u042f", "\\u0430", "\\u0431",
             "\\u0432", "\\u0433", "\\u0434", "\\u0435", "\\u0436", "\\u0437",
             "\\u0438", "\\u0439", "\\u043a", "\\u043b", "\\u043c", "\\u043d",
             "\\u043e", "\\u043f", "\\u0440", "\\u0441", "\\u0442", "\\u0443",
             "\\u0444", "\\u0445", "\\u0446", "\\u0447", "\\u0448", "\\u0449",
             "\\u044a", "\\u044b", "\\u044c", "\\u044d", "\\u044e", "\\u044f",
             "\\u2014"] :: [L.Text]
```

And in second I use finite automata in foldl function. (I wanted to use regexp but found no lib that supports function instead of string in sub like in python https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)

```
ununicode :: BL.ByteString -> BL.ByteString               
ununicode s = LE.encodeUtf8 $  parts $ LE.decodeUtf8 s where 

  parts :: L.Text -> L.Text
  parts = fst . parts' where
      lst (_, _, x) = x
      snd (_, x, _) = x
      fst (x, _, _) = x
      parts' :: L.Text -> (L.Text, Integer, L.Text)
      parts' = L.foldl f ("", 0, "") where
          f :: (L.Text, Integer, L.Text) -> Char -> (L.Text, Integer, L.Text)
          f p n | snd p == 0 = case n of
                    ('\\') -> (fst p, 2, lst p)
                    (x)    -> (L.singleton n, 1, lst p)
                | snd p == 1 = case n of
                    ('\\') -> (fst p, 2, lst p)
                    (x)    -> ((fst p) `L.snoc` n, 1, lst p)
                | snd p == 2 = case n of
                    ('u')  ->  (fst p, 3, lst p)
                    x      ->  ((L.snoc (L.snoc (fst p) 
                                                '\\')
                                         n),
                                1, 
                                lst p)
                | snd p == 3 = proc p n
          proc :: (L.Text, Integer, L.Text) -> Char -> (L.Text, Integer, L.Text)
          proc (text, 3, buff) n | isHexDigit n           = (text, 3, buff `L.snoc` n)
                                 | (len > 3) && (len < 6) = (L.append text
                                                                      (replacedChoice buff n), 
                                                             if n == '\\' then 2 else 1,
                                                             L.empty)
                                 | otherwise              =  (L.append text 
                                                                       (L.append "\\u"
                                                                                  (choice buff n)),
                                                             if n == '\\' then 2 else 1,
                                                             L.empty) where
                                  len = L.length buff
                                  choice b n = if n == '\\' then b else L.snoc b n
                                  replacedChoice b n = if n == '\\' 
                                                       then repl b 
                                                       else L.snoc (repl b) n

  repl :: L.Text -> L.Text
  repl "" = ""
  repl s  = (\v -> case v of 
      (Right x) -> L.singleton $ (\t -> toEnum t :: Char) $ fst x
      (Left x) -> error $ "impossible" ++ (show x)) (hexadecimal s)
```

I am just running my tests (all is very fast, except this) to see time.
Something like

```
it "converts url encoded string" $ do
        (ununicode $ BL.pack $ concat $ replicate 1000 ("error:\\u041d\\u0435\\u0432\\u0435\\u0440\\u043d\\u044b\\u0439\\u100cc" :: String))
         `shouldBe`
         ("error:\208\157\208\181\208\178\208\181\209\128\208\189\209\139\208\185")
```

It takes 0.5 sec for first implementation and from 5 to 15 for second. That's too much.

How can I make my second algorithm as fast as first (or even faster if it possible)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fast string processing in Haskell is somewhat of a black art.

Are you trying to do the same thing as the `jstring` function in the `aeson` package?

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.11.2.0/docs/Data-Aeson-Parser.html#v:jstring

Even if it's not exactly the same thing you might get some ideas by looking its implementation. It uses [attoparsec](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec) underneath which come in both strict and lazy versions.

Comment: Thanks. I get this encoded string using aeson as Lazy ByteString but I missed this function. I have Looked at the source now and it looks like do what I need.